# How to download RTools without using the CRAN website

Tags: r, rtools

Due to company regulation I cannot download RTools from the CRAN Website. Do you know a possibilty to install RTools inside the R Enviroment

Comment: the question seems a bit too minimalistic. You do have an internet connection but are not allowed to use the CRAN Website? or are you looking for a offline installer? please eleborate a bit more on the restrictions you have.

Comment: RTools is a collections of build tools unrelated to R itself used to build and compile packages. It’s not something you can install in R itself. It is a windows specific thing. Are you trying to build your own packages? Or typing to install packages from source code? Or GitHub?

Comment: The [installr package](https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=installr) has an `install.Rtools` function, but it [just downloads the source from the CRAN website](https://github.com/talgalili/installr/blob/master/R/installRtools.R#L15). So... not sure if that meets your criteria.

Comment: @Thomas
install.RTools worked. Our company has the policy, that you cannot install any 3rd party software. That is why I had to look for a solution inside R itself. I could download it and install it as well. Odd solution I know, but sometimes you have to be creative